# ListView different items click listener on custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, contextmenu

I have a `ListView` app and in the app I want different items click listener. The card view showld show a toast of selected item name, and on taping on the image button it should open a context menu for the particular item.

My adapter

```
class AdapterForList extends BaseAdapter {
public AdapterForList(Activity activity, ArrayList<ProviderVideoDetails> singletons) {
}
convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.XML_list_row, null);
final ImageButton I = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        final CardView C = (CardView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card);

C.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // should show a toast of selected item name
            }
        });

I.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // should open context menu of selected item
            }
        });*/
}
```

In XML_list_row

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                  <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image" />
           </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

in activity my context menu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.listVideos) {
        menu.add(0,0,0,"Op1");
        menu.add(0,1,1,"Op2");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
```

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: You've explained what you what to happen, but you haven't explained exactly what is happening or where you issue is (error/wrong response/no response).

Comment: I don't know how to implement it from adapter, that's my issue sir.

Comment: The code you have posted as "AdapterForList"  certainly cannot be correct. Part of your code is "just hanging in the air". Please post a reproducible example. I suggest you google a good example of how to implement a `ListView` you might even want to consider `RecyclerView`.